# Grouping a php object

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I've a php object that outputs as :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 25 
        [itemid] => 13 
        [studentid] => 9 
        [score] => 22 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst9 
        [lastname] => studentlast9
    ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 26 
        [itemid] => 13 
        [studentid] => 10 
        [score] => 23 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst10 
        [lastname] => studentlast10 
    ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [itemid] => 1 
        [studentid] => 1 
        [score] => 2 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst1 
        [lastname] => studentlast1 
    ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 2 
        [itemid] => 1 
        [studentid] => 2 
        [score] => 3 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst2 
        [lastname] => studentlast2 
    ) 
    [4] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 9 
        [itemid] => 5 
        [studentid] => 1 
        [score] => 6 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst1 
        [lastname] => studentlast1 
    ) 
    [5] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 10 
        [itemid] => 5 
        [studentid] => 2 
        [score] => 7 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst2 
        [lastname] => studentlast2 
    ) 
    [6] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 17 
        [itemid] => 9 
        [studentid] => 1 
        [score] => 10 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst1 
        [lastname] => studentlast1 
    ) 
    [7] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 18 
        [itemid] => 9 
        [studentid] => 2 
        [score] => 11 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst2 
        [lastname] => studentlast2 
    ) 
    [8] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 3 
        [itemid] => 2 
        [studentid] => 1 
        [score] => 3 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst1 
        [lastname] => studentlast1 
    ) 
    [9] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 4 
        [itemid] => 2 
        [studentid] => 2 
        [score] => 4 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst2 
        [lastname] => studentlast2 
    )
    [10] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 11 
        [itemid] => 6 
        [studentid] => 1 
        [score] => 7 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst1 
        [lastname] => studentlast1
    )
    [11] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 12 
        [itemid] => 6 
        [studentid] => 2 
        [score] => 8 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst2 
        [lastname] => studentlast2 
    )
    [12] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 19 
        [itemid] => 10 
        [studentid] => 1 
        [score] => 11 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst1 
        [lastname] => studentlast1 
    )
    [13] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 20 
        [itemid] => 10 
        [studentid] => 2 
        [score] => 12 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst2 
        [lastname] => studentlast2 
    )
    [14] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 7 
        [itemid] => 4 
        [studentid] => 1 
        [score] => 5 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst1 
        [lastname] => studentlast1 
    )
    [15] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 8 
        [itemid] => 4 
        [studentid] => 2 
        [score] => 6 
        [imagealt] => 
        [timemodified] => 0 
        [data] => 
        [firstname] => studentfirst2 
        [lastname] => studentlast2 
    )
)
```

As, one can see, there are only two `studentid` having different `itemid`. I want to group them and print it as a table like:

```
                  itemidid1    itemidid2   itemidid3
studentid1            x1          x2             x3
studentid2            y1          y2             y3
```

I'm trying the following code, but it displays all the values one below the other.

```
<?php foreach ($hits as $hit): ?>
            <?php if ($hit->studentid == $current_id): ?>
                <td> <?php echo $hit->score; ?> </td>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if ($current_id != -1): ?>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $current_id = $hit->studentid; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" id="<?php echo $hit->studentid; ?>" class="student-grade-data"> <?php echo $hit->firstname.' '.$hit->lastname; ?> </a></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $hit->score; ?>
                </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: "As one can see"...that array output is huge. Can you reduce the example input?

Comment: First loop over all objects and store them in buffer array grouped by IDs, than loop over that buffer and output HTML

Comment: show your query , `select * ....`

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question - when you say "there are only two `studentid` having different `itemid`" do you mean multiple instead of different? For instance `studentid` 9 and 10 only have `itemid` 13. `studentid` 1 and 2 have multiple instances of `itemid`. Do you want to exclude 9 and 10 from your table because they only have one `itemid`, and only show 1 and 2?

Comment: Another thing... in your table above where do the `x` and `y` prefixes come from, and what do they represent? They seem significant yet they are not in your source data, nor are they in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your query, add `group by` clause, like `group by field name`

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all objects and collect the objects in two arrays like:

```
$byStudentId[$hit->studentid] = $hit;
$byItemId[$hit->itemId] = $hit;
```

then you can get the columns by `array_keys($byItemId)` and finaly build the table by looping over $byStudenId